How to get an Nginx upstream to use a fallback when the primary host cannot be found
I'm currently migrating an internal app from docker to podman and I'm having to get a bit 'clever'.
Each user hitting the application needs to have upstream and locations configured AND the podman container needs to be running. Due to the nature of the app, we can't guarantee at any time that the podman container for the user will actually be running, though we will have definitions for the nginx location and upstream.
An example of the upstream directive looks like:
upstream goober_one_area {
    server goober_one_container:8080;
}

And the location looks like:
location /goober_one {
        rewrite /goober_one/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://goober_one_area;

        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_next_upstream_tries 3;
        proxy_next_upstream_timeout 10s;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # WebSocket Support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;

        proxy_redirect off;
}

When the goober_one_container isn't running, I of course get [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "goober_one_container:8080" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/environments/goober_one.upstream.conf:2. Makes sense.
To remedy this, the idea was to prop up a single view flask app that serves as a fallback so if the host could not be found in the upstream, it'll just go to this flask app that gives a rundown of the situation. I've got it set up in my docker-compose.yml file that I'm running through podman compose and that part works fine, but changing the upstream definition to be:
upstream goober_one_area {
    server goober_one_container:8080;
    server fallback:8080 backup;
}

doesn't net any results. Despite fallback:8080 being up, accessible, and serving as a prereq for nginx to even start in the first place, it gets to goober_one_container:8080 and just quits out.
How can I get this to just jump to the next server when the main container is not available?
UPDATE:
I found the DNS server for podman to use as my resolver, set that as:
resolver dns.address.com valid=30s;

and updated my upstream config to look like:
upstream goober_one_area {
    zone development_zone 64k;
    server goober_one_container:8080 resolve;
    server fallback:8080 backup;
}

The fallback works now! Unfortunately, nginx cannot find goober_one_container:8080, even though it can be reached at that address within the nginx container.
One step forward, two steps back.

Try checking the nginx error log. It might be in:
"podman container logs --latest CONTAINER_NAME".
If there are no errors there, try enabling error logging with error_log ttps://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log
There should be an error that caused goober_one_area to be skipped.
